# Split text file into multiple files using windows batch scripting

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, split

I need to split one text file into multiple files using windows batch script, could anybody light me up?

sample text file:

```
abc1-10
abc1-11
abc1-12
xyz2-01
xyz2-02
xyz3-01
xyz3-02
```

in this case, it has to split into 3 files, first one consists the lines `abc1-xx`, second one consists `xyz2-xx` and `xyz3-xx` go to the last one

Answer (score 6):

You could use a batch file, but why not just use [FINDSTR](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command?

```
findstr /R "^abc1-" sample.txt > file1.txt
findstr /R "^xyz2-" sample.txt > file2.txt
findstr /R "^xyz3-" sample.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: This is correct in an academic sense, but when the prefix is unknown and variable then it becomes unworkable.

Comment: And what happens if the data line contains the target string other than at the beginning?

Comment: thanks fthiella, I already came up with the solution after posting this message

Answer (score 6):

Use the cgwin command SPLIT.

Samples:

-split a file every 500 lines counts:

```
      split -l 500 [filename.ext]
```

For more: split --help

Answer (score 5):

This may help - it will split the text into separate files of

abc1.txt
xyz2.txt
xyz3.txt

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=-" %%a in ('type "file.txt"') do (
>>"%%a.txt" echo(%%a-%%b
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks foxidrive, I already came up with the solution after posting this message